# Javascript - create a singleton array out of object array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects:

```
[{
    name: "test",
    age: 20,
    gender: "male"
},
{
    name: "test2",
    age: 22,
    gender: "female"
}]
```

Frequently I need to create a singleton array which contains a specific property from the object array above, for example extract only the names from the array above and create an array from it:

```
NewArray = ["test","test2"]
```

Currently I loop over the object array and push the property I need to the new array.

Is there a quick way to do it in Javascript/ES instead of looping every time I need to get specific property?

Comment: That is an invalid object. Missing braces half-way?

Comment: I think that you mean array of objects `[{}, {}]`, not an object of 2 arrays `{[],[]}`.

Comment: Yeah @Solo thanks for correction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var people = [{
  name:'test1',
  age:20
}, {
  name:'test2',
  age:30
}]
let names = people.map(function(item) {
  return item.name
});
console.log(names);
```